# Force input to be decimal in @Html.Textbox

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i have a problem.
I have a Razor Textbox:

```
 @Html.TextBox("imp",   amount, new { @class = "alignRight", size = 5 })
```

I would like that , in input, user will write only decimal values.
How can i do? 
I think jquery could help me...but...what's the id of that textbox?

Comment: The text box's id will be "imp".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do via Jquery and Javascript as well

```
function isNumeric(evt)
{
 var c = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
 if ((c >= '0'  && c <= '9') || c == '.' )
    return true;
 return false;
}
```

And regarding Id, you can do it via class as well.
In your case it will be

```
@class = "alignRight"
```

Also from  http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?124756-Stop-pasting-of-invalid-text-into-decimal-only-textbox.

```
function validateDecimal(textboxIn)
{
    var text = textboxIn.value

    for(var x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        while(text.indexOf(x) != -1)
        {
            text = text.replace(x,"");
        }
    }

    if(text != "." && text != "")
    {
        textboxIn.value = "";
    }
}
```