# How do I limit the user to write only 4 digits in an input value?

Tags: jquery, html, input

I want to force the user to write in an input values, which have max 2 digits after "."
For instance : 24.14  or  5.7  or 0.5  or 8  and NOT 4.321 or 5.133121. How can I do that ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force input to be decimal in @Html.Textbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646219/force-input-to-be-decimal-in-html-textbox)

Comment: it's better to modify your question before moderator close it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution for  this. You can use this api from Jquery: [click here](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't force any thing to any body but you could format it to decimal after user type

```
 <input type="text" id="input_id">

 //format decimal value while typing
(function($) {
    $.fn.currencyFormat = function() {
        this.each( function( i ) {
            $(this).change( function( e ){
                if( isNaN( parseFloat( this.value ) ) ) return;
                this.value = parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(2);
            });
        });
        return this; //for chaining
    }
})( jQuery );


$( function() {
    $("#input_id").currencyFormat();       
});
```

[Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477892/in-jquery-whats-the-best-way-of-formatting-a-number-to-2-decimal-places)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [.toFixed()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp) method which converts a number into a string, keeping a specified number of decimals.

**sample**:

```
var myNum = document.getElementById("textboxID").value;
myNum = parseFloat(myNum).toFixed(2); //I fixed my precision to 2 digits after "."
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you:
here is the text input:

```
 <input type="text" id="tb1" >
```

And the JavaScript/JQuery code:

```
 $('#tb1').on('keydown',function(e){
 var textValue=document.getElementById('tb1').value;
if(textValue.indexOf('.')>=0 && e.which!=8 && e.which!=37 && e.which!=39 && e.which!=46)
   {
  textValue=textValue.split('.')[1];
   if(textValue.length>=2)
      return false;
   }
 });
```